# Running a piece of code just once in a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to attach an event handler to an object, and I placed this code on a button click event. However, I noticed that this will cause the same event to attach multiple times with each click.

Is there a way to run a piece of code on class creation? The class in question is a static class btw.

I can do something like:

```
if (bool == false)
{
attach event handler;
bool = true;
}
```

Just not sure if this is the right way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [static constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), that are (in principle) only run once per class.

Something like this:

```
public static class MyStaticClass
{
   public static int MyStaticProperty;

   //no accessors required, as this is never explicitly invoked
   static MyStaticClass() //no parameters either
   {
      MyStaticProperty = 100;
   }
}
....
//writes: 100
Console.WriteLine(MyStaticClass.MyStaticProperty);
```

However, if a constructor won't do it, because you have some parameters that need to be set, or there are some prerequisite steps that need to be done, I would indeed recommend a private boolean check, as you have done.

Answer (score 3):

You use a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx) - it will run on class creation.

> Constructors are class methods that are executed when an object of a class or struct is created. They have the same name as the class or struct, and usually initialize the data members of the new object.

For static classes, use [static constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx):

> A static constructor is used to initialize any static data, or to perform a particular action that needs to be performed once only. It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(Button1.Click == null)
  Button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myEventHandler);
```